# how to handle mobile back button for single page in ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Unable to handle the previous page response.[This is my form with labels If i submitting the form saved successfully and redirected to [home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeBGm.png)

This is home page - [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naArc.png).

I need to control the back buck button, Mean to say that is not go to the image1

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {alert("hi")}
```

I'm getting alert in all pages.

I want alert for single page.

Comment: Edit your question...post what efforts you have made to achieve it..

Comment: platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {alert("hi")}---am getting alert for all pages

Comment: above method will show alert every time you press **back button**

Comment: yes but i want for single page only..could you send me the code@codemonkey

Comment: Please, edit your question and insert there your code.

Comment: @timiTao  -- 
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {alert("hi")}- this is my code

Comment: @RATHNAKAR REDDY KALVA You have posibility to edit your own question - insert there your question, not in new comment.

Comment: @RATHNAKARREDDYKALVA I'm here to help YOU resolve problem, not for you - there are not in here, a free developers to do YOUR job. The quote think about your quote: "could you send me code for ionic2". If you don't understand the difference, then you will have a lot problems in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `platform.registerBackButtonAction` put this code

```
if( this.navCtrl.getActive().name=="urpage")
{
   alert("hi");
}
```

Comment: Thnaks for reply.. am asking for ionic 2 .but you were send in ionic1

Comment: Happy to help.accept this as answer if this helps you.